# Unfold/desugar scala macro

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala.js, scalajs-react

I am trying to write my own [scalajs-react components](https://github.com/chandu0101/scalajs-react-components) by wrapping existing JS-react components, so that they can be used from scala.js.

I am trying to understand how to do that by understanding how it is done [here](https://github.com/chandu0101/scalajs-react-components/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/chandu0101/scalajs/react/components/ReactInfinite.scala).

The problem is that I don't really understand macros very well, so I would like to rewrite [this line](https://github.com/chandu0101/scalajs-react-components/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/chandu0101/scalajs/react/components/ReactInfinite.scala#L25) without the use of macros.

How can I do that ?

Comment: You don't need to understand how macros work to be able to *use* them. And in this case it seems like you really just have to copy that line over to your component, and forget about it. You *could* of course write by hand the (probably monstrous) code that is generated by the macro instead of calling the macro, but that probably defeats the entire purpose of scalajs-react components. The motivation of your question is not clear enough for a better answer, IMO.

Comment: Thanks ! I try to figure out how to do that. It's not clear yet to me how can use these macros in my own code.

Comment: I guess I just can add this as a dependency : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.chandu0101.scalajs-react-components/macros_sjs0.6_2.11